# Cannot create a migration, or run a migration on my computer

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, entity-framework

**Updates on bottom**

Below is my console dump, which migrations execute in my main. (update-database)

This has been working for a prolonged time, and even earlier today. After running a code comparison the only change I have on record is the addition of a field named `__IsDisabled`. I tried it without the double underscore, because of the error, and I still have the same error.

Everything is in .NET Core 2.2. I cannot migrate to 5 anytime soon.

I am basically stuck as to this just doesn't make sense.

**Here is the Console dump.**

```
[22:34:40 Information]
LOADED: appsettings.json

[22:34:40 Information]
LOADED: appsettings.Development.json

[22:34:50 Debug] Lcp.Fortify.Startup
Applying Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer migration for ApplicationDbContext.

dbug: Lcp.Fortify.Startup[0]
      Applying Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer migration for ApplicationDbContext.
[22:34:52 Debug] Lcp.Fortify.Startup
Applying Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer migration for ConfigurationDbContext.

dbug: Lcp.Fortify.Startup[0]
      Applying Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer migration for ConfigurationDbContext.
[22:34:52 Debug] Lcp.Fortify.Startup
Applying Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer migration for PersistedGrantDbContext.

dbug: Lcp.Fortify.Startup[0]
      Applying Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer migration for PersistedGrantDbContext.
[22:34:52 Debug] Lcp.Fortify.Startup
Applying Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer migration for KeyManagementDbContext.

dbug: Lcp.Fortify.Startup[0]
      Applying Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer migration for KeyManagementDbContext.
```

**This is a known warning that has does not impact the build or migration.**

```
[22:34:57 Warning] Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Model.Validation
Property 'Id' on entity type 'WebFarmCache' is part of a primary or alternate key but has a constant default value set. Constant default values are not useful for primary or alternate keys since these properties must always have non-null unqiue values.

warn: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Model.Validation[20600]
      Property 'Id' on entity type 'WebFarmCache' is part of a primary or alternate key but has a constant default value set. Constant default values are not useful for primary or alternate keys since these properties must always have non-null unqiue values.
```

**This is the beginning of the confusing error.**

```
info: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure[10403]
      Entity Framework Core 2.2.6-servicing-10079 initialized 'ApplicationDbContext' using provider 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer' with options: MigrationsAssembly=Lcp.Fortify.Data
info: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20101]
      Executed DbCommand (172ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
      SELECT COUNT(*)
      FROM [dbo].[AuthConfig] AS [a]
[22:34:59 Error] Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command
Failed executing DbCommand (481ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
SELECT [a].[Id], [a].[AssociatedOrgCodes], [a].[AuthType], [a].[AuthenticationScheme], [a].[Authority], [a].[ClientId], [a].[ClientSecret], [a].[CssClass], [a].[DisplayName], [a].[ImageUrl], [a].[__IsDisabled], [a].[__scopes]
FROM [dbo].[AuthConfig] AS [a]
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Invalid column name '__IsDisabled'.
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.TryConsumeMetaData()
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.get_MetaData()
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite, SqlDataReader ds)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite, String method)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
   at System.Data.Common.DbCommand.ExecuteReader()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Internal.RelationalCommand.Execute(IRelationalConnection connection, DbCommandMethod executeMethod, IReadOnlyDictionary`2 parameterValues)
ClientConnectionId:XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX
Error Number:207,State:1,Class:16

fail: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20102]
      Failed executing DbCommand (481ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
      SELECT [a].[Id], [a].[AssociatedOrgCodes], [a].[AuthType], [a].[AuthenticationScheme], [a].[Authority], [a].[ClientId], [a].[ClientSecret], [a].[CssClass], [a].[DisplayName], [a].[ImageUrl], [a].[__IsDisabled], [a].[__scopes]
      FROM [dbo].[AuthConfig] AS [a]
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Invalid column name '__IsDisabled'.
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.TryConsumeMetaData()
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.get_MetaData()
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite, SqlDataReader ds)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite, String method)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
   at System.Data.Common.DbCommand.ExecuteReader()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Internal.RelationalCommand.Execute(IRelationalConnection connection, DbCommandMethod executeMethod, IReadOnlyDictionary`2 parameterValues)
ClientConnectionId:e3d152f6-24ac-4599-a500-bdd28d78d73b
Error Number:207,State:1,Class:16
[22:34:59 Error] Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query
An exception occurred while iterating over the results of a query for context type 'Lcp.Fortify.Data.ApplicationDbContext'.
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Invalid column name '__IsDisabled'.
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.TryConsumeMetaData()
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.get_MetaData()
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite, SqlDataReader ds)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite, String method)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
   at System.Data.Common.DbCommand.ExecuteReader()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Internal.RelationalCommand.Execute(IRelationalConnection connection, DbCommandMethod executeMethod, IReadOnlyDictionary`2 parameterValues)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Internal.RelationalCommand.ExecuteReader(IRelationalConnection connection, IReadOnlyDictionary`2 parameterValues)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryingEnumerable`1.Enumerator.BufferlessMoveNext(DbContext _, Boolean buffer)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.ExecutionStrategy.ExecuteImplementation[TState,TResult](Func`3 operation, Func`3 verifySucceeded, TState state)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryingEnumerable`1.Enumerator.MoveNext()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.LinqOperatorProvider._TrackEntities[TOut,TIn](IEnumerable`1 results, QueryContext queryContext, IList`1 entityTrackingInfos, IList`1 entityAccessors)+MoveNext()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.LinqOperatorProvider.ExceptionInterceptor`1.EnumeratorExceptionInterceptor.MoveNext()
ClientConnectionId:e3d152f6-24ac-4599-a500-bdd28d78d73b
Error Number:207,State:1,Class:16
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Invalid column name '__IsDisabled'.
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.TryConsumeMetaData()
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.get_MetaData()
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite, SqlDataReader ds)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite, String method)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
   at System.Data.Common.DbCommand.ExecuteReader()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Internal.RelationalCommand.Execute(IRelationalConnection connection, DbCommandMethod executeMethod, IReadOnlyDictionary`2 parameterValues)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Internal.RelationalCommand.ExecuteReader(IRelationalConnection connection, IReadOnlyDictionary`2 parameterValues)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryingEnumerable`1.Enumerator.BufferlessMoveNext(DbContext _, Boolean buffer)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.ExecutionStrategy.ExecuteImplementation[TState,TResult](Func`3 operation, Func`3 verifySucceeded, TState state)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryingEnumerable`1.Enumerator.MoveNext()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.LinqOperatorProvider._TrackEntities[TOut,TIn](IEnumerable`1 results, QueryContext queryContext, IList`1 entityTrackingInfos, IList`1 entityAccessors)+MoveNext()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.LinqOperatorProvider.ExceptionInterceptor`1.EnumeratorExceptionInterceptor.MoveNext()
ClientConnectionId:e3d152f6-24ac-4599-a500-bdd28d78d73b
Error Number:207,State:1,Class:16

fail: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query[10100]
      An exception occurred while iterating over the results of a query for context type 'Lcp.Fortify.Data.ApplicationDbContext'.
      System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Invalid column name '__IsDisabled'.
         at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
         at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
         at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
         at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)
         at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.TryConsumeMetaData()
         at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.get_MetaData()
         at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString)
         at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite, SqlDataReader ds)
         at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite, String method)
         at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
         at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
         at System.Data.Common.DbCommand.ExecuteReader()
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Internal.RelationalCommand.Execute(IRelationalConnection connection, DbCommandMethod executeMethod, IReadOnlyDictionary`2 parameterValues)
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Internal.RelationalCommand.ExecuteReader(IRelationalConnection connection, IReadOnlyDictionary`2 parameterValues)
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryingEnumerable`1.Enumerator.BufferlessMoveNext(DbContext _, Boolean buffer)
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.ExecutionStrategy.ExecuteImplementation[TState,TResult](Func`3 operation, Func`3 verifySucceeded, TState state)
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryingEnumerable`1.Enumerator.MoveNext()
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.LinqOperatorProvider._TrackEntities[TOut,TIn](IEnumerable`1 results, QueryContext queryContext, IList`1 entityTrackingInfos, IList`1 entityAccessors)+MoveNext()
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.LinqOperatorProvider.ExceptionInterceptor`1.EnumeratorExceptionInterceptor.MoveNext()
      ClientConnectionId:e3d152f6-24ac-4599-a500-bdd28d78d73b
      Error Number:207,State:1,Class:16
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Invalid column name '__IsDisabled'.
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.TryConsumeMetaData()
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.get_MetaData()
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite, SqlDataReader ds)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite, String method)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
   at System.Data.Common.DbCommand.ExecuteReader()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Internal.RelationalCommand.Execute(IRelationalConnection connection, DbCommandMethod executeMethod, IReadOnlyDictionary`2 parameterValues)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Internal.RelationalCommand.ExecuteReader(IRelationalConnection connection, IReadOnlyDictionary`2 parameterValues)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryingEnumerable`1.Enumerator.BufferlessMoveNext(DbContext _, Boolean buffer)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.ExecutionStrategy.ExecuteImplementation[TState,TResult](Func`3 operation, Func`3 verifySucceeded, TState state)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryingEnumerable`1.Enumerator.MoveNext()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.LinqOperatorProvider._TrackEntities[TOut,TIn](IEnumerable`1 results, QueryContext queryContext, IList`1 entityTrackingInfos, IList`1 entityAccessors)+MoveNext()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.LinqOperatorProvider.ExceptionInterceptor`1.EnumeratorExceptionInterceptor.MoveNext()
ClientConnectionId:e3d152f6-24ac-4599-a500-bdd28d78d73b
Error Number:207,State:1,Class:16
```

**Updates**

1. I built a design-time context class into the assembly with the ApplicationDbContext. This made it so that I could successfully generate a new migration, and update-database. However, there are still calls to the table, at the field that had not been implemented yet on the update which were failing. My data assembly makes no such call. Literally the only place the call could be made is during the migration and by the migration.

Comment: Have you created and run a migration against the database to add this column in? Or did you add the local property and forget to create and also apply the migration? Are your migrations applied programmatically? Is the code trying to use the column before the migration apply code has run? "invalid column name" could be better expressed as "the column __isdisabled in your query, is not present in the table AuthConfig"

Comment: This is a project and DB that I have been running against for years. The migration I did against it earlier in the day worked. The very first event in the code is to run migration before any sub-threads startup. The difference here and the other migration I did was on a model from another schema.  Basically, this is old hat work for me, until today. Until this migration, this code has been solid since 2.2 was released.

Comment: Specifically, I was just adding a new nullable, non-indexed, field.

Comment: I don't know what to say; SQLServer seems to be saying that the column isn't in the table, and you're saying that you've definitely done and run the migration that adds the column to the table. Which one of you is right?

Comment: This was from trying to run update-database. Now that I have had sleep, I see that I missed that.

I just don't get why the select statement is even being called on an update-database, when it has never been called before. Or if it has been, I haven't had an error before.

Comment: EF doesn't know that the DB hasn't been updated; you've added __IsDisabled to your client side entities and your context model, EF expects it to be on the server side. Delete a few more columns from random tables and watch EF blow up; it just assumes that what is in the model is in the DB< because that's what a migration is for; sync the model and the db

Comment: I'm going to draw out the timeline of events because when I wrote this out originally, I miscommunicated some assumptions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the comments from Caius Jard above. The error was caused by a select that shouldn't have been triggered against a model that hadn't been pushed.

Once I applied a manual update to the DB, and recorded the migration into the migration history table, I have not had this problem happen again.